# Is RTCSessionDescription.toJSON() supported in all browsers? Is is truly standardized?

Tags: json, webrtc, sdp

I see in the W3C WebRTC [specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/webrtc/) that RTCSessionDescription.toJSON() is supported.
I also see support for it on Mozilla website.
Question: Is this support available across all other browsers?
Is there any standard on the JSON conversion itself. I think the specs are silent about any details on the SDP to JSON conversion other than a one-liner reference to this support.
JSEP [specs](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-rtcweb-jsep-25) also does not throw any additional light either.

SDP is a simple key-value format. There can be, for example, multiple entries for the same key. Does JSON conversion represent this as an array of values? Is the order maintained?
Order in SDP is important. How is this taken care of in JSON conversion where properties have no significance in terms of their position in the object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That toJSON is describing the conversion of the RTCSessionDescription object which is basically a combination of type and sdp.  It does *not* convert the SDP to a JSON format.

Comment: What kind of person named that method?